# How to generate json data from a many to many database table?

Tags: python, json, peewee

I am using sqlite db and peewee as the ORM.

My data model is:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    nickname = CharField(index=True, unique=True)

class Circle(db.Model):
    name = CharField(unique=True)

class UserInCircle(db.Model):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name="in_circles")
    circle = ForeignKeyField(Circle, related_name="include_users")
    privilege = IntegerField()
```

What I need is to get a data format like the following:

```
[{"nickname": "urbainy", "privilege": 7, "in_circles": [{"circle_name": "world"}, {"circle_name": "test"}]}, {"nickname": "ywe", "privilege": 1, "in_circles": [{"circle_name": "family"}], {"nickname": "ymo", "privilege": null, "in_circles": []}]
```

So this is a nested json object. I tried marshmallow but I failed because of the many to many data structure. I can't get `in_circles` field all along time. I am beginner of programmer, so maybe this question is low level. But I really don't have idea to solve it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to use ORM way? Not sql-query?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, Yes, I prefer ORM way. I am not familiar with sql-query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now, I adopt this way to solve the problem:

```
@login_required
def setting():
    users_in_circles = (User.select(User.nickname,
                                    UserInCircle.privilege,
                                    Circle.name.alias("circle_name"))
                            .join(UserInCircle, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
                            .join(Circle, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
                            .order_by(User.id))
    users_in_circles_data = []
    user_nickname = ""
    user_in_circles = []
    for user_in_circle in users_in_circles.naive():
        if user_in_circle.nickname != user_nickname:
            user_nickname = user_in_circle.nickname
            user_in_circles = [dict(circle_name=str(user_in_circle.circle_name), privilege=str(user_in_circle.privilege))]
            users_in_circles_data.append(dict(nickname=user_in_circle.nickname, in_circles=user_in_circles))
        else:
            user_in_circles.append(dict(circle_name=str(user_in_circle.circle_name), privilege=str(user_in_circle.privilege)))
            users_in_circles_data[-1].update(nickname=user_in_circle.nickname, in_circles=user_in_circles)
    print(users_in_circles_data)
    return render_template("admin_setting.html", circles=Circle.select(), users=User.select(), users_in_circles_data=users_in_circles_data)
```

Somehow I think maybe there is some other neat way to implement this, such as marshmallow or some other tools. If you know a better solution, welcome to reply to my post then.

Comment: I think sql way is better :))). Too many rows for easy action.